# How to convert String with GMT Values to Date in Excel?

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I have a list of date values like, `November 23, 2016 4:21:02 PM GMT-06:00`. How to sort this in Excel? I would like to know the possible formula (or how to make one) to get the date out of it.

Comment: You just want the date?

Comment: Yes, that would be enough.

Comment: If the format is always consistent, find the third space in the text, take all the text to the left of the third space, convert to date.

Comment: If the time zone adjustment would change the date (given a time close to midnight), should the date be adjusted?

Comment: @Jeeped That would be interesting to know, but am not doing that right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this formula:

```
=INT(--LEFT(A1,FIND("GMT",A1)-1))
```

Then format the date as you would like.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. Can you share me the link to know other features or manipulation with date for Excel?

Comment: The thing to remember is that a date in excel is saved as a number.  The whole number being the number of days since 1/1/1900 and the decimal being the time of day divide by 24.  Buy parsing the string into a date that can be reognized by excel, excel will automatically change it into a number.  The `--` forces that.

Comment: I just realized the brilliance of what you did Scott. Finding the "GMT" is way easier than finding the third space, then the simple INT function to strip the time. Lovely.